# jQuery CSS to pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery as little as possible and I would like to translate some jQuery code to pure JS.

I have this:

```
$(".myDiv").css({"width": 500});
```

What is the pure JS equivalent of the code above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');

// If you want to get elements using its class name
// var els = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');

for(var i = 0, length = els.length; i < length; i++) {
   els[i].style.width = '500px';
}
```

By using `forEach`:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');

els.forEach(function(el, ind) {
  el.style.width = '500px';
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zuh44cL/)

Comment: Your `for` loop should be `for(var i = 0, length = els.length; i < length; i++)`. It is faster than acessing the `length` property all the time.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel may I know what is the difference?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Such micro optimisations are rarely useful - in this case the body of the for loop is more than likely causing a reflow of the page, it'll dwarf the time spent in the for loop itself.  It's usually best to stick with what's most readable until you have a measureable issue.

Comment: Be aware of the use of [**.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on **array-like objects**, it lacks of browsers compatibility, especially with IE.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve the same affect, but you could go with something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv').forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.width = '500px';
});
```

querySelectorAll selects all of a particular CSS selector as a collection of DOM elements. forEach iterates through the collection, passing the currently selected element to the inner function, which is then styled with style.width.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.width = "500px";
})
```

`querySelectorAll` gets the elements, then you iterate over the elements and set the style for each one.

Comment: Be aware of the use of [**.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on **array-like objects**, it lacks of browsers compatibility, especially with IE.

Comment: If OP is worried about old browsers, he should probably not try to "use jQuery as little as possible" in the first place. Just go all out on jQuery to support older browsers. @pedromartinez

Comment: Also, for anybody who wants to, there are polyfills for most (all) new array methods, like Some, forEach, Every, filter and so on.

Comment: Well it's very important to mention it, he didn't want to use jQuery, so propably he is aiming an old browser here, so when we provide a pure JS solution, it needs to be compatible with all browsers. for future readers as well. If there are polyfills, they are worth of mention here.

Comment: "he didn't want to use jQuery, so propably he is aiming an old browser here" -> the reverse should be true. The more you need to support older browsers, the more you should be resting upon jQuery.

Comment: If he really needs to support older browsers, older versions of jQuery remain available which provide most of the same APIs. It's one of the primary strengths of jQuery.

Comment: Every single answer so far provided, without using jQuery, requires more modern browsers than jQuery does. `querySelectorAll`, `Array.from` -- these features are from the last few years.

Comment: He said ***I am trying to use jQuery as little as possible*** so when we provide a pure JS solution, it need to be compatible with all browsers (or mention the lack of browser compatibility) and fits the needs of future users seeing the post, that's it.

Comment: No answer here is compatible with all browsers. Old browsers didn't implement many of these functions that are available by default in new browsers. That's why jQuery exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to get all the elements with this class and then iterate over them and use `style.width` to change their width:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")).forEach(function(div) {
  div.style.width = "500px";
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")).forEach(function(div) {
  div.style.width = "100px";
});
```

```css
.myDiv{
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">A</div>
```

**Note:**

We use **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** to treat the result of [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) as an `Array` as it's returned as a `Nodelist` or an  ***array-like object*** and doesn't have the `Array` properties and the ***[`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)*** method in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use cssText

```js
css(document.getElementById("red"),"color:red;font-size:24px")


function css(el,cssText){

el.style.cssText=cssText;


}
```

```html
<div id="red">something</div>
```